# How to add python code to Nodejs Express API?

Tags: python, node.js, express, python-requests

I am creating a [`Express.js`](https://expressjs.com/) API that offers json data when request is received by an end-point.
for example- [like this one](https://api.jokes.one/), jokes api, weather api, etc

 But I have some logics that I want to implement in `python`  as there are some **very good libraries like `requests`** in python.
I have seen in many places that many softwares can be written in multiple languages, [here](https://jserd.springeropen.com/articles/10.1186/s40411-017-0035-z)

### Demonstration (what I want to achieve):

I have an api called `example.com`
Someone made a **get request** to `example.com/api/v1/category/json-data?quantity=4`
Now, the `app.get(example.com/api/v1/category/json-data?quantity=4)` route in my code will be triggered and from there I want to call my `python` code that will do some job and finally what user wants will be sent back.

- How can I achieve this?
- What should my folder structure look like?
- How to manage both `python` and `npm` dependencies together?
- Please share any **article, documentation or video** I can refer.

Comment: Please share this question, if you know someone who can help

Comment: You could run python code in a child_process and get the result back from that child_process.  You can't run it in the nodejs process itself as ndoejs only knows how to run Javascript.  If you're just trying to make http requests to other sites, there's no reason to use python for that as there are many good libraries for that in Javascript that run in nodejs such as `got()`, `node-fetch()`, `axios()`, etc..  See [here](https://github.com/request/request/issues/3143) for a listing of them.

Comment: @jfriend00 Actually, I want to do web scrapping. So python has the best solution, that is what I think.

Comment: @jfriend00 Also, please tell What should my folder structure look like?

Comment: Well, there's plenty of good solutions for web scraping in Javascript.  But, if you insist on using Python for that part of the project, you can just make your Python code and your Javascript into separate projects each managed by their own system and then you can call one from the other with an API between the two.  In this way, the web scraping is a replaceable component.  Directory structure is entirely up to you.

Comment: @jfriend00 I am mainly focusing on learning to use python in a nodejs-based project/api/web-app. And I don't want to make the python and JavaScript parts separate into two different projects. Please refer to the **Demonstration** section of my question to understand my .goal better.

Comment: @jfriend00 Can you please add a proper answer for how to manage the python and npm dependencies in this case? And please provide some quality reference content if it is possible.

Comment: I've said what I have to contribute.  Your question makes it sounds like you're asking for someone to design your project, tools and layout for you.   That isn't generally how stackoverflow works.  You ask a specific question and people try to supply a good answer to that specific question.  My recommendation is that you either run a given python scrape as a child_process or you create a python http server and send scrape requests to it from your Express server.  Either will work just fine.  I don't have any suggestions on how to organize the code on disk or what tools to use.

Comment: @jfriend00 no problem, i can understand. thank you